# How do I reverse the order of this stacked bar chart in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

The bars in this chart are in the wrong order. I have tried to fix this using google and ChatGPT but I have hit a road block.

Here is my R code:

```
COChart <- ggplot(data_2019, aes(x = year)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = CO_emissions, fill = "green"), stat = "identity", position = "stack") +
  geom_bar(aes(y = CO_emissionsSD, fill = "red"), stat = "identity", position = "stack") +
  labs(title = "CO Emissions from Pleasants Power Plant from 2001 to 2023", x = "Year", y = "Tons") +
  theme_light()
```

and here is the output:
[image]

Comment: what is the good order ? red under green ? If yes, you may try COChart <- ggplot(data_2019, aes(x = year)) +   geom_bar(aes(y = CO_emissionsSD, fill = "red"), stat = "identity", position = "stack") +

  geom_bar(aes(y = CO_emissions, fill = "green"), stat = "identity", position = "stack") +
  labs(title = "CO Emissions from Pleasants Power Plant from 2001 to 2023", x = "Year", y = "Tons") +
  theme_light()

Comment: @Beeflight31 ; I'd guess that i is to do with wanting the legend text labels and the legend colours to correspond. Is that correct Carson?

Comment: adding the `fill` values like that doesn't do what you expect. You can add `scale_fill_manual(values=c(green="green", red="red"))`

Comment: Please be careful, I'm pretty sure the two different `geom_bar` calls won't stack on top of each other... @user20650: that works, but easier to either move `fill = "green"` outside of the `aes()`, or use `scale_fill_identity`.

Comment: @Axeman ; by moving fill = "green" outside the aes then they will lose the legend (without the addition of other code) but agree on the stack (I  suspect this plot isn't doing exactly what is wanted)

Comment: @user20650 Im not sure a legend with a green and red box saying "green" and "red" would be very useful ;)

Comment: You need to modify your data - stack CO_emissions and CO_emissionsSD into one column.  Then use this column as fill inside first aes inside ggplot. You can set custom colors with scale_fill_manual function as suggested.